# NDK need gnustl_static std::string instead of std::_ndk1::string

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I am hooking an existing library that is compiled using gnustl `std::string` instead of libc++ `std::_ndk1::string`. If I try to set or access these strings I just get garbage. How do I convert my `std::string` to `std::_ndk1::string` and vice versa in my hook application?

I cannot compile my hook with "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_shared" because it no longer exists and other libraries in use require libc++.

The documentation mentions this https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support "The various STLs are not compatible with one another. As an example, the layout of std::string in libc++ is not the same as it is in gnustl" which is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 4):

To use **gnustl**, you could compile all your native code with [NDK r.17](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases#ndk-17c-downloads) or older. This is a dangerous path, because many important bugs, including security-related, have been fixed since then.

Another unsupported (and not recommended) way to deal with your problem is to get the **gnustl** sources from NDK r.17 and compile them with the latest NDK version.

Your best option is to have all your dependencies rebuilt with a recent version of NDK and its **c++_shared** runtime library.

Comment: Unfortunately, when dealing with hooking existing applications, I'm stuck with whatever ancient NDK they compiled with. I posted my solution for this above.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with (for now, really not ideal):

StringsProxy.cc

```cpp
#include "StringsProxy.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

__attribute__((visibility("default")))
extern "C" StringsProxy::StringsProxy(const char* contents)
{
    set_string = std::string(contents);
}
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
extern "C" StringsProxy::StringsProxy(uintptr_t str) {
    set_string = *reinterpret_cast<proxy_string*>(str);
}
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
extern "C" const char* StringsProxy::c_str() {
    return set_string.c_str();
}
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
extern "C" const uintptr_t* StringsProxy::ptr() {
    return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t *>(&set_string);
}
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
extern "C" StringsProxy::~StringsProxy() {
}
```

StringsProxy.h

```cpp
#ifndef __STRINGSPROXY_H__
#define __STRINGSPROXY_H__
#include <string>

typedef std::basic_string<char> proxy_string;

class StringsProxy
{
public:
  /* Initialize StringsProxy with a pointer to an existing string */
  StringsProxy(uintptr_t str);
  /* Initialize StringsProxy with a new string */
  StringsProxy(const char* str);
  /* Get C string */
  virtual const char* c_str();
  /* Get pointer to string for injection */
  const virtual uintptr_t* ptr();

private:
  proxy_string set_string;
};
#endif
```

Compile this into a shared object using the old NDK with `-DCMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE=gnustl_static`

Then link this shared object to the hooking program (in CMakeLists):
`target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/abiproxy/build/armeabi-v7a/libabiproxy.so)`

Then in the hooking program, can be used like this:

```cpp
#include "abiproxy/StringsProxy.h"
void *setUriDebug(uintptr_t a1, uintptr_t stri) {

    auto y = StringsProxy(stri);
    LOGI("URI CALLED %s", y.c_str());

    return setUriDebugOld(a1, stri);
}
```

Or in reverse:

```cpp
StringsProxy assetNameBaseProxy = StringsProxy("https://example.com/");
void setResourceUrl(uintptr_t* a1, int a2) {    
    *(a1 + 1) = *assetNameBaseProxy.ptr();
}
```

This isn't by any means a *good* solution, but it works for my use-case.

Comment: This way you isolate the gnustl strings from your code. It looks OK, but why not rebuild your whole code with **gnustl** and old NDK?

Comment: older NDKs have a intrinsic TEXT_RELOCATION problem, and as you know, modern androids simply reject loading libraries with TEXT_RELOCATIONs

Comment: @AlexCohn Some incompatibility with the hooking library.